# Why does SQL Server return some rows while still executing the query, and sometimes not?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

There are queries where when we hit "execute", it shows some rows and it keeps growing, but the query is not over yet. Yet sometimes, it waits until the end of the query.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to control this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The answer, as usual (alright, most of the time), lies in the execution plan.

There are certain operators that require all rows to arrive at them before they can start processing those rows, and passing them downstream, for example:

- Hash Join (on building the hash table)
- Hash Match
- Sort (Except Hash Flow Distinct)

They're either called blocking, or stop and go operators because of this, and they're often chosen when the optimizer thinks it'll have to process a whole lot of data to find your data.

There are other operators that are able to begin streaming, or passing any found rows along immediately

- Nested Loops
- Index supported Merge Joins
- Stream Aggregates

When queries start returning data immediately, but don't finish immediately, it's usually a sign that the the optimizer chose a plan to locate and return some rows quickly using operators that have a lower start up cost.

This can happen because of row goals introduced either by you, or by the optimizer.

It can also happen if a bad plan is chosen for some reason (lack of SARGability, parameter sniffing, insufficient statistics, etc.), but that takes more digging to figure out.

For more information, check out Rob Farley's blog [here](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/02/17/the-ssis-tuning-tip-that-everyone-misses/)

And Paul White's series on row goals [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals), [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/row-goals-part-2-semi-joins), [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/03/sql-plan/row-goals-part-3-anti-joins), and [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/03/sql-performance/row-goals-part-4-anti-join-anti-pattern).

It should also be noted that, if you're talking about SSMS, rows only appear once an entire buffer has been filled, not just willy-nilly.

Answer (score 14):

If I understand what you're observing, this is how Management Studio *renders* rows, and has little to do with how SQL Server *returns* rows. In fact often when you are returning large results to SSMS and attempting to render them in a grid, SSMS can't keep up and SQL Server ends up waiting for the app to process more rows. In this case you'll see SQL Server accumulating `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` waits.

You can control it somewhat by using Results to Text instead of Results to Grid, since SSMS can draw text faster than it can draw grids, but you'll likely find this can affect readability depending on the number of columns and the data types involved. Both are impacted by when SSMS decides to actually write results out to that pane, which depends on how full the output buffer is.

When you have *multiple* statements, and you want to force the buffer to render output results to the messages pane, you can use a little printing trick in between statements:

```
RAISERROR('', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
```

But this won't help when you're trying to get SSMS to render rows more quickly when all the output is coming from a single statement.

More directly, you can control it by limiting how many results you are rendering in SSMS. I often see people complain about how long it takes to return a million rows to the grid. What on earth anyone is going to do with a million rows in an SSMS grid, I have no idea.

There are some hacks like [**`OPTION (FAST 100)`**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135455/what-does-option-fast-in-select-statement-do), which will optimize for retrieving those first 100 rows (or any 100 rows if there is no outer `ORDER BY`), but this can come at the cost of much slower retrieval for the remainder of the rows and a plan that is more inefficient overall, so isn't really a go-to option IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not about SQLServer per se but:

- SQLServer
- network
- SSMS as client application

> > Is there a way to control this?

**Short answer**:

1. Try `sqlcmd` instead of `ssms` or `sqlcmd`-mode of `ssms`
2. Check your connection and session settings

**Long answer**:

Of course! But not **one** - prob

1. Execute your query with `sqlcmd` or in `sqlcmd`-mode in ssms.
2. If you want exclude role of network - run your query on server with Shared Memory connection.
3. If query performance is unsatisfiable even with Shared Memory connection - analyse your execution plans. If query performs bad through network - call your network network administrator for help. If your query performs bad only in SSMS - read further.
4. Now we are sure that problems are on client side(ssms in this case). Look at connection and session settings in SSMS. **Don't believe ssms interface** and check with SQL Profiler: find your connection by `spid` and you get full list of session settings. Compare with settings of `sqlcmd` session. If nothing clicks - copy all session settings from profiler into your query script, execute in `sqlcmd`-mode and  gradually switching settings you will find your culprit.

Good luck!